# Android switch between apps

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two apps and I want to switch between the apps after clicking on a button.

I use this code:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("at.mycompapp");
if (i == null) {
    return;
}
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

My problem is that the app is started new, but when the app is already running, it should just switch to this app without restarting it.

Comment: The `target app`(you want to run) is your app?

Comment: add singleTask attribute in activity in manifest file.

Comment: You don't need to add CATEGORY_LAUNCHER, that is already there. Ignore the suggestion to use `launchMode="singleTask"`, this is unnecessary and will cause more problems. Post the manifest of both apps.

Comment: Also, there is a long-standing Android bug that causes this kind of behaviour. Maybe you are seeing that. To check, install both apps on the phone. Go to Settings->Apps and force stop both apps. Then start the one app from the HOME screen and press your button and see if the behaviour is correct.

Comment: @EthanChoi Yes both apps are from me

Comment: @keyur9779 Single Task does not change the behaviour

Comment: @Peter Why you don't used to `custom scheme`?? I think this functions(run another app) is can be solve use `custom scheme`.

Comment: @Peter  yes it will not change behaviour if your acitivity or process is killed in the background and more if you acitivity is coming from background to forground onrestart will get called, but in case if your activity is singleTask same this wil happend, but you will get onNewIntent() system callback as extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using custom scheme to get to the right point in my apps.